# sql query find double entry

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some trouble with a SQL query to find double entries:

mytable

```
id(int), eid(int), date(date), pid(int)
```

some inserts:

```
1, 10, '2017-05-04', 1  
2, 20, '2017-05-04', 1  
3, 10, '2017-05-04', 5
```

I want to find double entries for eid to one date
result:

```
1, 10, '2017-05-04', 1  
3, 10, '2017-05-04', 5
```

My first idea was with GROUP BY and HAVING but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT id, eid, date, pid, COUNT(pid) AS NumOccurrences
FROM `mytable`
HAVING ( COUNT(pid) > 1 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `exists()`

```
select *
from mytable t
where exists (
  select 1
  from mytable i
  where t.eid = i.eid
    and t.date = i.date
    and t.id <> i.id
    )
```

---

`inner join` version, though you may get extra rows depending on how many duplicates you have for each pair. If so, you could add `distinct`.

```
select t.*
from mytable t
  inner join mytable i
    on t.eid = i.eid
   and t.date = i.date
   and t.id <> i.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this solution: `SELECT DISTINCT id, eid, date, pid, COUNT(pid) AS NumOccurrences FROM mytable`